# Let $m$ be a cardinal number less than $q$. Prove that a set of cardinality $q$ contains a subset of cardinality $m$.

Tags: cardinals, ordinals

I think it is true but I don't have a clue as to how I'm supposed to construct such a subset (working under ZFC)

Answer (score 2):

Let $\kappa$ be the least ordinal of cardinality $m$ and $\lambda$ the least ordinal of cardinality $q$. Then $\lambda$ is a subset of $\kappa$. Now use the fact that any set of cardinality $m$ admits a bijection with $\kappa$, and any set of cardinality $q$ admits a bijection with $\lambda$.

Comment: Why is it that $\lambda$ is a subet of $\kappa$?

Comment: @John: It’s a basic fact about ordinals. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are any ordinals, then exactly one of the following holds: $\alpha=\beta$, $\alpha$ is a proper initial segment of $\beta$, $\beta$ is a proper initial segment of $\alpha$.